# Layout help in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to implement a basic text to speech software. I have a GridView consisting of images. I need to have another view above this to which thumbnail of the images clicked can be placed. 
Can anyone help me which view supports placing the thumbnail images?

Comment: The thumbnails must be placed linearly (horizontally).. It must also be scrollable if there are many images placed on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple imageviews or modify your gridview to that similar on the android dev site. search hello gridview

Comment: Thanks for the reply..if a gridview is placed with a single row, can we limit the number of images visible at a time ?
the other images must move out of the screen and could be seen moving a sidebar or something..

Comment: Not sure if you need a gridview for that... just put some images padded with horizontal orientation bound in a scrollview. dont forget that scrollview will need a linear layout aswell.

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the API examples that googles has you will find what you are looking for. Have a look in the part of [Views](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html)

To the examples of Gallery and the sample of Grid.